# how to stop method from calling if return key is pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I have iphone app in which i am calling code one on `textFieldShouldReturn` and other on `didEndEditing`.

I want that when user return press the app should not called `didEndEditing` code and if user does not press return then call.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if (textField==tagTextField) {
        [self showAnimationBack];
    }
    if (textField.tag==2 && [valueReturn isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
       if (textField.text.length > 0 || ![tagTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
           [textField resignFirstResponder];
           [tagArray addObject:tagInputField.text];
           [tableView reloadData];
           tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);
          [tableView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
           [tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
           tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
           tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
           [self showAnimationBack];
     }
}

 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag == 2)
    {
        if (textField.text.length > 0 || ![tagTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [tagArray addObject:tagInputField.text];
        [tableView reloadData]; 
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);
        [tableView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
        [tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
         tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
         tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
         [self showAnimationBack];
     }
}
```

I call this also when user press return

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
       valueReturn=@"Yes";
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isEditing` value, as you (probably) resign the text view from first responder when the return key is pressed, `textFieldDidEndEditing` should have the text field at not-editing mode when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this a proper way of doing it but you can try this. Declare a variable `isReturnPressed` and make it `YES` in `textFieldShouldReturn:` and make it `NO` in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` . So you can check the condition as follows..

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if (isReturnedPressed == NO) {
      // Do your stuff

   }
   else {
       isReturnedPressed = NO
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.